# Getting a list of unique rows using sql DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

Given the following table, I am trying to select all the entries from the carCode column that have a UNIQUE e-mail address.  What would the SQL select statement for this be?  I've tried the following, but it doesn't appear to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT carCode, emailAddress, COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM myTable
WHERE (
carCode != ''
)
GROUP BY carCode;
```

Here's the table columns:

```
ID | carCode | emailAddress | fName | lName
```

And given the following example:

```
1 | cc001 | a@b.com | fname1| lname1
2 | cc001 | a@b.com | fname2 | lname2
3 | cc001 | b@b.com | fname3 | lname3
4 | cc001 | c@b.com | fname4 | lname4
```

Only rows 1, 3 and 4 should be returned or 2, 3 and 4, because 1 and 2 have the same code AND e-mail address.

Please advise.

P.S. Just to clarify, I am trying to count all the instances of car codes, but if a duplicate e-mail address is found for the same car code, to only count that e-mail address once. Does this clarify what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `having` clause to eliminate row 1 (it has duplicates):

```
SELECT carCode, emailAddress, 1 as cnt
FROM myTable
WHERE carCode != ''
GROUP BY carCode, emailaddress;
having count(*) = 1
```

For your revised question, the answer is simply a group by:

```
SELECT carCode, emailAddress, count(*) as cnt
FROM myTable
WHERE carCode != ''
GROUP BY carCode, emailaddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT  carCode, emailAddress, count(*) AS count
FROM myTable
WHERE carCode != ''
GROUP BY carCode, emailAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT  emailAddress, carCode,  COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM myTable
WHERE (
carCode != ''
)
GROUP BY carCode;
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Add emailAddress to the GROUP BY, remove the DISTINCT:

```
SELECT carCode, emailAddress, COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM myTable
WHERE carCode != ''
GROUP BY carCode, emailAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a `DISTINCT` here at all,  you just need to group by both the carCode and the emailAddress if you want to get the count of records for each distinct car code and email address combination.

```
SELECT carCode, emailAddress, count(ID) as `count`
FROM myTable
WHERE carCode <> ''
GROUP BY carCode, emailAddress
```

Comment: The car codes can be duplicates, it's the e-mail address that MUST be unique whether the car code is unique or not.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @steacha The question is, what are you trying to count?  Are you wanting to find the number of records associated with each distinct email address, or the number of records associated with each distinct carCode and email address combo.  Your OP is unclear because you don't mention specifically what you are trying to count, just that you are trying to select all carCodes that have a unique email address.

Comment: My bad, to clarify, I am trying to count all the instances of car codes, but if a duplicate e-mail address is found for the same car code, to only count that e-mail address once.  Does this clarify what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to do it using a `LEFT JOIN`; just return all rows that don't have a row with a lower ID and same code/email;

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable a
LEFT JOIN myTable b
  ON a.emailAddress = b.emailAddress
 AND a.carCode = b.carCode
 AND a.ID > b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

[SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c19b/2).

The advantage of this approach is that you get the complete rows for the results, if you really just need code and email, you should use a `GROUP BY` as many other answers suggest.